# How to make table cells of fixed size irrespective of their content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which contains dynamic content so the height of each row is varying - what I want is to fix the height of the table irrespective of the content. The content can be any length and can also have images.

I tried the following in CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
}
table td:nth-child(2n+2) {
  width: 200px;
}
table td:last-child {
  width: 100px;
}
table tr {
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>content1</td>
    <td>content 2</td>
    <td>content 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content1</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>content 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It worked fine but when there was no content in any of the cells, or if content reduces a cell, it collapses. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/YD9Gg/)

Comment: I am not seeing this "collapse": http://jsfiddle.net/YD9Gg/4/ -- this maintains the table height even though none of the cells have any content. It IS however different on different browsers. On IE, the width collapses, but not the height. On Firefox and Chrome, the width and height are the same whether there is content or not.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YD9Gg/5/ Is this what you want to achive? To stretch columns verticaly?

Comment: @Sófka i want every row of fixed size (height and width) and overflow content not to show or show with scroll and

Comment: @BCT I think that you can't do that with table cells, you'd have to change their display type or use other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/CfdJK/)):

```
table td
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}​
```

with browsers that support `inline-block`. (Altho I'm not sure if this is a good solution.)